# How to check a field empty or not in MySQL / C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table for stock transfer and there is a integer field called trnsno. I need to get the max value of that. If it is empty, the trnsno is 1.

```
     sql = "SELECT MAX(`trnsno`) FROM stktransfer";
                   //...
//...
    
                    if (config.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0))))
                        {
                            strTrnsNo = "1";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strTrnsNo = (Convert.ToInt32(config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0)) + 1).ToString();
                        }
    
                    }
```

It says " Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type."
I am new to C# and please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the check in c# by comparing to [`DbNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=net-5.0):

```
object objTrnsNo = config.dt.Rows[0][0];
strTrnsNo = DbNull.Value.Equals(objTrnsNo) ? "1" : objTrnsNo.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) to check for NULL and this example would return -1 instead

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(`trnsno`),-1) FROM stktransfer
```

Comment: How to stop ,returning a record, when null?

Comment: You get always a responsey but you can use NULL or nstead of -1